# Left and Top positions are not getting set for absolute positioned element

Tags: html, css

Element with id *logo* is positioned with ***absolute***. By default the left and the top position of the element which is set with the position absolute should be 0 and 0 right..? But here some kind of malfunctioning is happening. Can anybody tell me the exact reason of why this is happening..?

Here is what i have,

### HTML:

```
<body>
 <div id="header">
    <h1>
      <a href="homePage.html">jackalQuest</a>
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Who the hell is Developer.?</li>
      <li>About the site</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="logo" >
 </div>    
</body>
```

### CSS:

```
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sM8BT/1/)

Comment: because you haven't set the left and top values

Comment: @VikingBlooded By default the left and top values would be 0 right..? Then why should i need to set it explicitly..?

Comment: browser dependent, always specify them

Comment: `browser dependent` Are you having any concrete proof for that.? I don't want to follow your instructions blindly..!

Comment: experience and test it yourself and see. Also, there is not "default" for absolute positioning, it just removes it from teh flow of the document and allows you to place it wherever you want.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Okay fine.! Some kind of research is needed towards that, i guess so. since you doesn't know anything about that..! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BlueMoon Yeah sure.. I was looking for one of that..! Thanks a bunch..!

Comment: @BlueMoon Are you a tamil guy..? why dont you expose yourself to me..? Curious..! :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes...that's why I support it! I prefer to stay anonymous here ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```